# unable to move the list items in the carousel when buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple carousel without using any plugins in jquery and javascript. My problem is that the viewport does not show the next or previous list items on clicking the appropriate buttons. My code is:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body onload='createList()'>
        <div id="carouse">
            <button id='btn-prev' onclick='showPrev()'><img src="orange-towards-left.png"></button>
            <div id="viewport">
                <ul id="items">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button id='btn-next' onclick='showNext()'><img src="orange-towards-right.png"></button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function createList(){
                var html="";
                for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
                    html += "<li> Content " + (i+1) + "</li>";
                }
                document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = html;
            }

            function showNext(){
                var $curr = $('#items li.current');
                console.log('Current Index :: ', $curr.index());
                $('#viewport ul').animate({right: '240px'},1000,function(){
                    $curr.find("li:last").after($curr.find("li:first"));
                        //$(this).css({marginLeft:0});
                });
                 console.log('Current Index (after):: ', $curr.index());
            }

            function showPrev(){
                var $curr = $('#items li.current');

                $('#viewport ul').animate({right:'240px'},1000,function(){
                    $curr.find("li:last").before($(this).find("li:first"));
                    //$(this).css({marginLeft:0});
                }); 
            }
```

**CSS**

```
#carouse{
                display: inline-flex;
                /*visibility: hidden;*/
            }

            #viewport{
                display:block;
                width: 240px;
                height: 125px;
                position: relative; 
                overflow: hidden; 

            }

            #items{
                list-style: none;
                position: absolute; 
                padding: 0; 
                margin: 0; 
                width: 240px; 
                left: 0; 
                top: 0; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                list-style-type: none;
                float:left;
            }

            #items li{
                float: left; 
                margin: 0 20px 0 0; 
                padding: 1px; 
                height: 121px; 
                border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; 
                width: 236px; 
            }

            #btn-prev, #btn-next{
                  background: none;
                  border: 0px;
                  width: 30px;
                  height: 38px;
                  margin-top: 30px;
            }

            #btn-next img{
                width: 8px;
                height: 15px;
            }

            #btn-prev img{
                width: 8px;
                height: 15px;
            }
```

I don't know where the mistake is. I am trying this for the first time. Any help is appreciated. I apologize if I have repeated a question asked before.

Comment: provide a fiddle please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *lot of things* missing! I am not going to write an essay here as there are loads of tutorials such as [this](http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery) as to how to build a basic carousel using jQuery. Please go thru a few of them to learn what the basics are. It's good to know you're trying on your own to build one as opposed to just downloading one from the web.

Few things though:

- When you're using jQuery, please use it to the maximum extent possible.
- Do not use inline event handlers, such as `onclick="showNext()"` etc.
- Padding/margin on carousel items (`li` in your case) isn't a good idea as they make it a bit tricky to set dimensions. Have them in HTML within them.

I have only amended your code with the above points included to create a basic carousel (with no clones as the one's you were doing by placing the first element last etc.). You should really make it a [jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) with options if you'd like to reuse them. This is only a demo and feel free to adapt this code to suit your needs.

```
(function createCarousel() {

    var $container = $('#items');
    var current = 0;
    var $html = $();

    for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        $html = $html.add($("<li/>", { html: "Content " + (i+1) }));
    }
    $container.empty().append($html);

    var $items = $container.find("li");
    var itemsCount = $items.length;
    var itemWidth = $items.first().outerWidth();
    $container.width(itemWidth * itemsCount);
    $items.width(itemWidth);

    $("#btn-prev").on("click", showPrev);
    $("#btn-next").on("click", showNext);

    function showNext() {
        current = current >= itemsCount - 1 ?  0 : (current + 1);
        $container.animate({
            left: -(current * itemWidth)
        }, 250);
    }

    function showPrev() {
        current = current <= 0 ? itemsCount - 1 : (current - 1);
        $container.animate({
            left: -(current * itemWidth)
        }, 250); 
    }
}());
```

I've created a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cewktd4z/) with the full code in a fiddle. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you @lshettyl. Worked like a charm. Have altered the code to suit my needs. The link has been rather helpful too.